# Django http POST error

Tags: python, django

[image]

I am using the chrome postman extension to test out Django's request and response functionality as I'm going to need to POST data to a django app. My apps view is:

```
def index(request):
    # loop through keys
    for key in request.POST:
        value = request.POST[key]
    # loop through keys and values
    output =""
    for key, value in request.POST.iteritems():
    output= output + str(key) + " " + str(value) + "<br>"

    return HttpResponse(output)
```

When I send the request I get:

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Help
Reason given for failure:
    CSRF cookie not set.
```

How can I fix this?

Edit: Here is the output after your recommended changes:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decorate your view with [csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt). For this to work, you need to add 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES variable. csrf_exempt basically marks your view for being exempted from any CSRF checks. More details [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf)

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    # loop through keys
    for key in request.POST:
        value = request.POST[key]
    # loop through keys and values
    output =""
    for key, value in request.POST.iteritems():
    output= output + str(key) + " " + str(value) + "<br>"

    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Comment: Thanks praveen, you got it working! please see the update above.

Comment: Thanks. I can't find the solution elsewhere